# Ivy-dispatching-done (M-o) action list is not showing all options

Tags: projectile, ivy, counsel

I use `counsel-projectile-switch-project` to pop up a list of projects and `M-o` to bring up the action  list, but the action list is like this.
[image]
and there's no way to scroll to get the top options like "o - default", "f - find file" etc. Every key I tried is "not bound".

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'ivy-read-action-function' to either 'ivy-read-action-ivy' or 'ivy-hydra-read-action' if you have installed 'ivy-hydra'.
https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2397